# How to fix "Cannot send headers; headers already sent" error in magento version 1.9.3.3?

Tags: header, file, magento-1.9.3.3

> a:5:{i:0;s:147:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in
>   /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php,
>   line 1";i:1;s:1783:"#0
>   /home/waterc/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115):
>   Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)

If you have any idea please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below link,It will help you.

[How to fix “Cannot send headers; headers already sent” in Zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Check,have any space issue before start `<?php`
and also check any raw HTML area in .php file.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Nagaraj Juro

Yes, after removing that space getting error:

404 error: Page not found.

Comment: Now working fine ?unless check your URL @Ashish.

Comment: No, getting error 404  @Nagaraj Juro

when we clear all cache and load any page 1st time, getting error 404 error: Page not found.

Comment: What file you recently edited,I think there is any problem in .htaccess file.

Comment: Header issue is resolved now.

Comment: Getting another issue, if we clear cache of magento and then after we load home page then displayed 404 error page not found.